# show alert msg if location.search is missed by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.location

the page url is `example.com/1/page.html?user=123456`

need to check if the current page url contains

> example.com/1/page.html

without

> ?user=123456

because this is dynamic variable

show alert msg hello .. by javascript check current url

```
 if ( window.location.href = "example.com/1/page.html") {
alert("hello");
}
```

but not working

another idea !!

Answer (score 0):

Well window.location.href is a string so you could treat it as such and do some manipulation to remove the query part of the URL ( ? bit ) or you could look into a string contains function.

Look into JS indexOf() or split()

Answer (score 0):

use pathname

```
if ( window.location.pathname = "/1/page.html") {
alert("hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do (split the string on ?, should not break if none) :

```
if (window.location.href.split("?")[0] === "example.com/1/page.html") {
    alert("hello");
}
```

Comparison is made with `==` or `===` not `=` (assignment)

`window.location.href = "example.com/1/page.html"` means window.location.href takes the value `"example.com/1/page.html"` (don't even know if you can write this property)

Comment: it make example.com alert hello & is === not working for variables?

if (window.location.href.split("?")[0] ==="variable") {
    alert("hello");
}

Comment: sorry when i click on jsfiddle it alert hellow

but i need to alert for only one example.com/1/page.html not on any page host the code i hop to understand my question

Comment: I'm very sorry but you just don't understand my answer

Comment: oh no brother but you dunno understand my Q , i have a site has multi pages i want to make the event for one page without adding js line inside but adding in index

Comment: OK you win. Then explain what my fiddle does. That should be easy for you.

Comment: hhhh i'm mamdouh winningstar :D

you want to define the page url with split part of url after ? but when i try it works for all urls in my simple site

i search for another solution .. window.location dont solve my pro 

thanx for reply

Comment: & sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.location.pathname`instead of`window.location.href`

That'll give you just the path

```
if ( window.location.href = "/1/page.html") {
   alert("hello");
}
```